# Vue.js directive v-html not updating if the model is overwritten

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

By running the following code (a Vue.js component), I expect that, after the AJAX call returns, both the `v-html` directive and the `console.log()` display the same value.

On the contrary, `v-html` is stuck with "loading...(1)" even though `obj.html` has a different value, as `console.log()` confirms.

The behaviour is caused by `getObject` overwriting `obj`, and being afterwards `obj.html` undefined for a short time before `getHTML` returns (all this happens in function `created`).

**Can please someone explain whether this is Vue's desired behavior (doc links are welcome), or whether should I submit a bug report, or finally whether I am simply structuring my code in a bad way?**

Thanks in advance

```
<template>
    <main v-html="obj.html || 'loading... (1)'">
    </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Post',

    data: function () {
        return {
            obj: {
                html: 'loading... (2)'
            }
        }
    },

    created: async function () {
        this.obj = await this.getObject()
        this.obj.html = await this.getHtml()
        console.log(this.obj.html)
    },

    methods: {
        getObject: async function () {
            const resp = await this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            return resp.body[0]
        },
        getHtml: async function () {
            const resp = await this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            return resp.body[0].title
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems vue data objects are not deeply reactive, which means that altering a property will not trigger change detection in the template.

Try rearranging the `created` hook to compose the full object before assigning it to the data property. That way when the template reacts it will see the `html` property of `obj`.

Ref [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zloxkx75qx)

```js
created: async function () {
  const fetchedObj = await this.getObject()
  fetchedObj.html = await this.getHtml()
  this.obj = fetchedObj;
  console.log(this.obj.html)
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `getObject` returns a `String` so at the first line of created hook

`this.obj = await this.getObject()`

you change the reference of the `obj` and you make it pointing to a string and then you try to put a property on a string, which does not work ;)

it's like you would do 
`this.obj = 'test'` 
then 
 `console.log(this.obj);`
`// test`

and then 
`this.obj.abc = 'whatever'`
`console.log(this.obj.abc);`
`// undefined`

You would need to parse the object before, see `JSON.parse(string)`

Update:
If this is not the case i.e you somehow have an object coming from that service.
Then the only problem I can think is that you lose the reference of your original `obj` and `v-html` is still pointing to the old one. In that case you have to avoid modification of the root `obj` or you can use the vue `$set` method: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: your update is the answer i was looking for: my real code is returning an object from `getObject`, i did a mistake while trying to simplify it for posting this question